# Python to control Arduino

Tags: python, machine-learning, arduino

I want to develop a machine learning algorithm that will control the traffic lights to optimize the traffic flow. For the DEMO, I'll like to figure out a way to control an Arduino with 4 Traffic Lights for cars and 4 Pedestrian Lights ( 20 LEDs in total ), but all the control must come from a Python script that will define the timings.

How do I program the Arduino to read the code from the USB and run it?

How do I write the Python script to send a new Arduino script to USB everytime the parameters change ?

Comment: It is likely that you will not send the Arduino a new script. What is more likely is that you have a script within the Arduino that is listening on the Serial COM port, and waiting to receive specific values that you can use to trigger certain actions. Use the python script to send those values to the specific COM port in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to upload the StandardFirmata to your Arduino. From there on you'll be able to use the `pyfirmata` library to access the hardware.

This is example code from realpython.com

```
import pyfirmata
import time

board = pyfirmata.Arduino('/dev/ttyACM0')

while True:
    board.digital[13].write(1)
    time.sleep(1)
    board.digital[13].write(0)
    time.sleep(1)
```

As you can see, you'll be able to write directly to the pins and time it however you want.

I have not used this library yet, so I can't give you any parctical advise.
I usually run my code on a raspberry and connect the arduino over usb.

Check this link for the whole tutorial: https://realpython.com/arduino-python/